# EF Core ocorre num erro ao aplicar update-database

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, asp-net-core

Estou a criar a tabela `AspNetUSers` sendo que ao aplicar **update-database**

Ocorre o seguinte erro

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NULL,
>       `LockoutEnabled` bit NOT NULL,
>       `AccessFailedCount` int NOT N' at line 14

Estou a utilizar uma base de dados mysql
E pelo que percebi o problema ocorre nesta linha `LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),`

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUSers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUSers", x => x.Id);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUSers");
    }
```

Retirei o campo `//LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),` e acaba por criar as tabelas.
Mas como faço este campo ser compativer com o mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Ao criar a entidade, o Provider do MySQL olha para a propriedade que você passa no Type Constraints do mapeamento, como `DateTimeOffSet` não é um tipo `Nullable<T>` então o mapeamento quebra, tente trocar a linha citada para:</s>

```
LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset?>(nullable: true)
```

## UPDATE

Após os comentários abaixo, foi visto que o problema é do provider do MYSQL que não interpreta corretamente o tipo de dados DateTimeOffSet por ser um tipo de dados exclusivo do SQL Server, vide [pergunta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103607/will-does-mysql-support-datetimeoffset). Na [documentação do provider Pomelo.MySQL](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/79) existe um Workarround para trabalhar com DateTimeOffset.

Basicamente existem duas alternativas para corrigir o problema:

Converter o DateTimeOffSet para DateTime UTC e armazenar os dados.

- **Prós:**

  1. Comparação e ordenação serão trabalhadas pelo próprio banco de dados;
  2. Você irá armazenar apenas 8 bytes de espaço para cada informação no banco.
- **Contras:**

  1. O contexto do TimeOffset (SQL) poderá ser quebrado;
  2. O contexto do Timezone (SQL) poderá ser quebrado.

Armazenar no banco uma representação em String da data e utilizar uma propriedade não mapeada com a conversão para o tipo de dados desejado.

- **Prós:**

  1. O contexto do TimeOffset (SQL) será preservado;
  2. O contexto do Timezone (SQL) será preservado.
- **Contras:**

  1. A ordenação e comparação não será a ordenação do mecanismo do banco de dados;
  2. O tamanho de da informação no banco de dados pode ser de até 33 bytes ("* 2016-10-10T13:49:58.2065722+00:00").

A documentação ([neste link](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/79)) esta mais clara e oferece material de referencia:

[DateTime vs DateTimeOffSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset/14268167#14268167)

[Armazenando DateTime e DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715620/storing-datetime-utc-vs-storing-datetimeoffset/9314893#9314893)

Comment: Não corrige essa solução

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103607/will-does-mysql-support-datetimeoffset

Comment: Então é uma questão específica do Provider do MySQL, vou editar a resposta com um conteúdo da documentação do provider Pomelo.MySQL

Comment: criei no banco de dados directamente no mysql desta forma LockoutEnd datetime e funcionou apesar de nao saber se depois não dará problemas futuros em alguma coisa

Comment: Você seguiu a orientação que eu estava colocando na resposta, mais complementei a mesma para ficar mais clara e ajudar quem mais tiver a mesma dúvida.